# Determine if complex matrices are similar

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, solution-verification, jordan-normal-form, similar-matrices

> Consider the complex matrices
> $$
> \begin{array}{c}
> A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
> -2 & 4 & 3 \\
> 0 & 10 & 9 \\
> 0 & -16 & -14
> \end{array}\right)
> \qquad \text{ and }\qquad
> B=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
> -4 & -5 & -2 \\
> 0 & -2 & 0 \\
> 2 & 5 & 0
> \end{array}\right)
> \end{array}
> .$$
> Determine whether $A$ is similar to $B$.

**Attempt:** I am tempted to say they are similar since they have the same rank, characteristic polynomial (and therefore determinant, trace and eigenvalues with algebraic multiplicities), geometric multiplicities of eigenvalues, minimal polynomial and Jordan normal forms, up to a permutation of the Jordan blocks, but on the other hand I think they are necessary but not sufficient conditions for similarity.

Comment: Two matrices are similar if and only if they have the same Jordan form

Comment: Same Jordan forms should be enough.

Comment: Does this work even if their Jordan forms (which have two blocks) have their blocks permutated? @markvs

Comment: Yes. The order of blocks does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state that the two matrices have the same Jordan normal form. But every matrix is similar to its Jordan normal form.